# LaTeX misses the horizontal line of the "+"

Tags: math-mode, align

[image]

This is how it looks like in the output. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} %Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
    \begin{align*}
            \vert \vec{a} + \vec{b} \vert^2 &= \langle \vec{a} + \vec{b}, \vec{a} + \vec{b} \rangle\\
            \vert \vec{a} + \vec{b} \vert^2 &= \langle \underbrace{\vec{a}, \vec{a}}_{\vert \vec{a} \vert^2} \rangle + 2 \langle \vec{a}, \vec{b} \rangle + \langle \underbrace{\vec{b}, \vec{b}}_{\vert \vec{b} \vert^2}\rangle\\                                  &\le \vert \vec{a} \vert^2 + 2 \vert \vec{a} \vert \cdot \vert \vec{b} \vert + \vert \vec{b}\\
                                            &=  \bigl(\vert \vec{a} \vert + \vec{b} \vert \bigr)^2\\
            \vert \vec{a} + \vec{b} \vert^2 &<  \bigl(\vert \vec{a} \vert + \vec{b} \vert \bigr)^2 & \vert \sqrt{}\\
             \vert \vec{a} + \vec{b} \vert  &<  \vert \vec{a} \vert + \vert \vec{b} \vert
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I am using the following packages (its a general document I can use for all kind of things):

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amsmath} %Erweiterer Mathemodus
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links
%\usepackage{subfig} %Um mehrere Grafiken via {subfigure} in ein eine {figure}-Umgebung zu tun
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
```

Comment: Please can you add your `\documentclass{...}` into your code? In your mathematical code there is, in my opinion, little order :-)

Comment: For me it looks like a rendering problem. What viewer are you using? Try zooming in the pdf or using another viewer. If it doesn't help, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for us to play with.

Comment: i made a screenshot and made it smaller with paint. i am using sharelatex.com

Comment: i edited the documentclass, i dont know how to make it here looking readable, hope somenone edits it right xD

Comment: @LillienSabrinaGluch: I can see the horizontal line, but it's surely viewer-dependent. Download the resulting PDF and then view it in Adobe Reader (rather than the online rendering provided by Overleaf).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this example is you expected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amsmath} %Erweiterer Mathemodus
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links
%\usepackage{subfig} %Um mehrere Grafiken via {subfigure} in ein eine {figure}-Umgebung zu tun
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, cancel}
%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
%Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
%\providecommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\providecommand{\inner}[2]{\left\langle#1,#2\right\rangle}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\abs{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}^{2}
&=\inner{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}&\\
\abs{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}^{2}
&=\underbrace{\inner{\vec{a}}{\vec{a}}}_{\displaystyle\abs{\vec{a}}^{2}} + 
2\inner{ \vec{a}}{\vec{b}} + \underbrace{\inner{\vec{b}} 
{\vec{b}}}_{\displaystyle\abs{\vec{b}}^{2}}&\\
&\leq \abs{\vec{a}} + 2\abs{\vec{a}}\cdot\abs{\vec{b}}+ \abs{\vec{b}}&\\
&\leq \left(\abs{\vec{a}} + \abs{\vec{b}}\right)^{2}&\\
{\abs{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}}^{2}
&\leq \left(\abs{\vec{a}} + \abs{\vec{b}}\right)^{2}&\\
\sqrt[\cancel{ }]{{\abs{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}}^{\cancel{2}}}
&\leq\sqrt[\cancel{ }]{{\abs{\vec{a}} + \abs{\vec{b}}}^{\cancel{2}}}&\\
\abs{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}
&\leq\abs{\vec{a}} + \abs{\vec{b}}&\square\\
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Inequality]

Comment: [Update](https://gist.github.com/carlosal1015/33d1c6df9da11a1be178fa95db42cd07)